# Passing arguments to anonymous function of module

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var patient = (function (options) {
        var age = options.age;
        var name = options.name;

        function getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        function setName(val) {
            name = val;
        }

        function getAge() {
            return this.age;
        }

        function setAge(val) {
            age = val;
        }
        return {
            getAge: getAge,
            setAge: setAge,
            getName: getName,
            setName: setName
        }
    })();
});
```

I realize that I'm never passing any options in my example here.
If I try to do something like `patient.setAge('100')` and then `console.log(patient.getAge())` I get an error saying `cannot read property Age of undefined`.  The overarching theme that I'm trying to get at is within a module, how can I emulate consturctors to instantiate a new patient object while keeping all the OOP goodness of private variables and all that jazz.

I've seen some examples of constructors in a module pattern on here and I haven't understood them very well. Is it a good idea in general to have a constructor in a module?  Is its main purpose similarity with class-based languages?

Comment: There’s no constructor here… why don’t you just use one? Private variables are overrated. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a constructor inside a module is the problem and I'm wondering how to do that/if it's really ever necessary or better practice.

Comment: I was trying to simulate a constructor with passing in the options object (but obviously I didn't quite understand something right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a constructor:

```
function Patient(options) {
    options = options || {};

    this.age = options.age;
    this.name = options.name;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var patient = new Patient();
});
```

You can put it inside a module if you want. What you shouldn’t do is provide getters and setters, especially ones that don’t do anything. If you’re exposing a variable through two properties to get and set it, it should just be one property.

Comment: How do you do that?  I agree that getThis and setThat is verbose, but I don't know how to do it the jQuery way.

Comment: Does the constructor go inside of the module or outside?  Is it not

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: There’s no jQuery way, there is no magic, and it doesn’t matter whether you put it inside or outside the module. If it’s part of your “module” (did I mention modules don’t exist in JavaScript?), go ahead and put it inside.

Comment: I meant like $(textBox).val('setting') vs. $(textBox).val()//getting for the getting and setting with one property.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: That’s a function that takes one argument, checks whether it’s `undefined`, and does one thing or another based on that. (You can also check `arguments.length`.) Not cleaner. Are you trying to build a jQuery?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the underpinnings a little better is all.  I like the style of the module pattern and was curious about how I could make, say, 100 of these patients are objects and say something to a constructor and still have the privacy the closure provides in the anonymous function.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: You can make `age` and `name` variables inside the constructor and create the object’s methods inside the constructor instead of through the prototype, which is exactly the same approach as the module pattern. (It’s not a *good* approach, though. Try not to apply other languages’ everything to JavaScript.)

Comment: why isn't it a good approach?  I'm learning and making lots of...non-successes and trying to fill up my tool bag :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: It’s rare to truly need private variables, but it’s not rare to need to call a method off of a prototype or inherit a prototype, and the two are mutually exclusive (functions on `Patient.prototype` can’t access variables scoped to `Patient`, but they can access properties of their `this`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   function Patient (options) {
        options = options || {};
        var age = options.age;
        var name = options.name;

        function getName() {
            return name;
        }

        function setName(val) {
            name = val;
        }

        function getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        function setAge(val) {
            age = val;
        }
        return {
            getAge: getAge,
            setAge: setAge,
            getName: getName,
            setName: setName
        }
    });  // pass empty object 

$(document).ready(function () {
    var p1 =  new Patient({});
   var p2 =  new Patient();
    var p3 =  new Patient({age:20});
     var p4 =  new Patient({name:"abcd"});
    var p5 =  new Patient({age:21, name:"abcd"});
});
```

Comment: This is good to know, but this won't let me create multiple patient objects, will it?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie I made change according to your requirement. now you can create patient object as many as you want. also you can pass age and name see above example.